# ReferenceError: students is not defined

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, node-modules

hello m new to nodejs and trying to fetch students data at index of attendance but it says: students is not defined this is folder structure https://ibb.co/d5Q0GwR

error:

```
   ReferenceError: D:\nodejs\node_project\views\attendance\index.ejs:17
   15|         </thead>
   16|         <tbody>
>> 17|             <% students.forEach(function (student) { %>
   18|             <tr>
   19|                 <td>Tiger Nixon</td>
   20|                 <td><%= student.student_name %></td>

  students is not defined
```

controller:

```
  const express = require('express');
  var router = express.Router();
  const mongoose = require('mongoose');
  const Attendance = mongoose.model('Attendance');

  router.get('/', (req, res) => res.render('attendance/index'));

  router.get('/student', (req, res) => { 
Student.find((err, docs) => { 
    if (!err) { res.render("student", {
                   students: docs
               });
     } else { 
        console.log('Error in retrieving students record :' + err);
         } 
     }); 
  });

  module.exports = router;
```

student controller:

```
   paste.ofcode.org/HkXdi3vxZaYPGd4Rx9mLKg
```

Comment: Student is your model?

Comment: index.ejs does not have `students`. You render `students` variable in student.ejs

Comment: I have rendered it, u can see

Comment: @ForamTrada yes I has a model Student

Comment: Provide  `students` object .

Comment: @PushprajsinhChudasama student controller: paste.ofcode.org/HkXdi3vxZaYPGd4Rx9mLKg

Comment: it's normal that it doesn't find `docs` you sent to student.ejs, cuz you don't use this datas in `\views\attendance\index.ejs`

Comment: so what should I do.

Comment: You should try foreach loop on render page where you sent datas.

Comment: can u show me code bcoz I am new to it

Comment: I'm sure there's nothing wrong with your code. I'm just saying you're using your code in the wrong render page. Try using same code in student.ejs

Comment: i use this code at student controller but still same error router.get('/attendence', (req, res) => { 
 Student.find((err, docs) => { 
  if (!err) { res.render("attendance", {
              students: docs
          });
   } else { 
    console.log('Error in retrieving students record :' + err);
     } 
   }); 
});

Answer (score 2):

When you access `router.get('/student'` you pass `students` into the EJS with `res.render("student", { students: docs })`.

When you access `router.get('/'` you just say `res.render('attendance/index'))` and **don't pass  anything** into it, let alone an object that defines students.

You need to do there what you do in `/student`.

Comment: now it showing error in another line:  ReferenceError: D:\nodejs\node_project\views\attendance\index.ejs:17
    15|         </thead>

    16|         <tbody>

 >> 17|             <% students.forEach(function (student) { %>

    18|             <tr>

    19|                 <td>

    20|                     <input type="text" name="at_reg_no" value="<%= student.student_reg_no %>" style="border: none;">

Answer (score 0):

In line 9, Student was called as a model, but when you imported express and other models, in line 4, you imported Attendance.

You should import the School model and run the code again.

```
const Student = mongoose.model('Student');
```